# проанализировать строку

Tags: c++, строки, поиск

необходимо ввести N строк и в каждой из них найти и выписать (в структуру?) : число,слово между символами (например [] ), и одно из двух ключевых слов(например рядовой/сержант (enum?)). Какой наилучший способ реализовать данную задачу?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что именно вам нужно сделать. Вам нужно в каждой введенной строке отдельно подсчитать, сколько имеется заданных слов, заключенных в символы []?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow дана одна из N строка, в ней есть 1 слово между [], число и еще одно из двух слов(сержант/рядовой). Нужно выписать все три элемента

Comment: Ну, так опишите это в своем вопросе. Покажите, как может выглядеть входная строка, что из нее надо извлечь или что в ней надо подсчитать.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас строка всегда строго такого формата как бы описали, то можно сделать так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>

enum Rank{
    Soldier,
    Sergeant,
    Unknown
};

struct Data{
    int i;
    std::string s;
    Rank r;
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, Rank &rank){
    static const std::string soldier("рядовой");
    static const std::string sergeant("сержант");

    std::string s;
    is >> s;

    if(s == soldier){
        rank = Rank::Soldier;
    }else if(s == sergeant){
        rank = Rank::Sergeant;
    }
    else{
        rank = Rank::Unknown;  
    }

    return is;
}

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, Data &data){
    is >> data.i;

    is.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '[');
    std::getline(is, data.s, ']');

    is >> data.r;

    return is;
}
```

Использовать потом это можно так:

```
Data d;
stream >> d;
```

где `stream` любой поток ввода. Хоть из файла, хоть из строки, хоть с клавиатуры. Вот пример со строкой:

```
#include <sstream>

int main(){
    std::string input("42 [привет]  рядовой");
    std::stringstream stream(input);

    Data d;

    stream >> d;
    std::cout << d.i << std::endl; //42
    std::cout << d.s << std::endl; //привет
    std::cout << d.r << std::endl; //0 -> Rank::Soldier
}
```

[Полный пример](http://cpp.sh/3yvqz)

Comment: я только учусь, не могли бы вы объяснить мне про класс istream ?

Comment: @topl3niy, `std::istream` это базовый класс для потоков ввода.

Comment: @topl3niy, функция `std::istream& operator>>(std::istream &is, Rank &rank)` будет вызвана если написать, например, `Rank r; std::cin >> r;`. Аналогично для структуры `Data`

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJIb, is>>data.i будет игнорировать все не цифры в строке?

Comment: @topl3niy, `is>>data.i` ничего не игнорирует. Эта строка считывает число из потока.

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJIb ну то есть считывает только числа

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJIb  можно про std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max() поподробнее?

Comment: @topl3niy, максимальное количество символов в потоке. `is.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '[');` означает *проигнорировать все до символа '['*

Comment: @yrHeTaTeJIb что-то не так с выводом в программе, она не выводит слово между [], номер и т.д. А когда я попробовал создать динамический массив из N элементов класса Data и с помощью него вывести несколько результатов, то после 1-ой итерации программа выводит те же самые 0 0 и завершается.

Comment: @topl3niy, по вашему комментарию сложно понять что происходит. Напишите небольшой отрывок кода, который воспроизводит ошибку, и задайте новый вопрос